# Change border or background color on control being validated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

I'm adding validation to an existing asp.net web app built with web form. The input textbox controls I need to validate are created dynamically on the server side.

While creating the textboxes, I can also create `RangeValidator` controls and set its `ControlToValidate` to the ID of the textbox.

When validation fails, `RangeValidator` displays an error message at where the validation control is placed.

But I rather change the `border` or `background-color` to red of the textbox instead. How can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom logic to your validators both sever side and client side. check this link for help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Loop over all validators and add specific CSS class to controls. I use master page, so need to find controls in content placeholder.

```
        const string ErrorCssClass = "error";

        Validate();
        if (IsPostBack && !IsValid)
        {
            var content = Form.FindControl("MainContent") as ContentPlaceHolder;

            foreach (BaseValidator validator in Validators)
            {
                if (validator.IsValid)
                    continue;

                var controlToValidate = content.FindControl(validator.ControlToValidate) as WebControl;
                if (controlToValidate != null && !controlToValidate.CssClass.Contains(ErrorCssClass))
                    controlToValidate.CssClass += " " + ErrorCssClass;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want help validating or changing the color (or both), but I just tried this little two-button app and it seems to work. Granted, I'm not using any dynamic control names and banking that "testText" is the first and only "testText" control on the page. You might also want to add some validation to ensure the control exists.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Name = "testText";
        this.Controls.Add(tb);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("testText",true)[0];
        tb.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but that's not what I'm asking for. I have a range validator that validates a textbox. When the textbox contains invalid input, the range validator displays error message. But I don't want to display error message, instead, I want to make the textbox red.

Comment: Oops, thought you meant you were moving validation server side. You could do something similar, but include Controls.Find("RangeValidator") and then if(!RangeValidator.IsValid) tb.BackColor = red. I'm not really sure how this can be done without involving the server side... :/

Comment: The textboxes are generated on server side, but validation can happen either on client or server side which is not a concern. The issue I have is the default behavior for RangeValidation is to change its appearance, not its target's appearance. I want to change its target's appearance.

Answer (score 0):

As Irfan said, you can use a custom validator and implement on the server validate event the logic. However, a more direct aproach would be to check if the page is valid and the check if the rangevalidator is not valid. Keep in mind to set the displaymode to none if you don't want the validator to render any message.

```
if(!Page.IsValid && !myRangeValidator.IsValid)
{
    // simplified, you will need to search for the control in the whole hierarchy
    var ctrlToValidate = Page.FindControl(myRangeValidator.ControlToValidate) as WebControl;
    if(ctrlToValidate != null)
    {
        ctrlToValidate.BorderColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

this being said, I prefer the custom validator approach. The good thing is you can almost reuse all the code above. Just remove the first if, add the range validation, set the args.IsValid = false and then use the rest of the code.